# PHP not exporting MySQL database in right format

Tags: php, html, mysql, excel

so I am having trouble exporting the data from MySQL into excel

```
    $output = '';  
 if(isset($_POST["export_excel"]))  
 {  
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM Logs ORDER BY item";  
      $result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);  
      if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
      {  
           $output .= '  
                <table class="table bordered="1">  
                     <tr>  
                          <th>Sort</th>  
                          <th>Unit Size</th>  
                          <th>Quantity</th>  
                          <th>Price per Unit</th>  
                          <th>Time</th>  
                     </tr>  
           ';  
           while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
           {  
                $output .= '  
                     <tr>  
                          <td>'.$row["Sort"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["Unit Size"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["Quantity"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["Price per Unit"].'</td>  
                          <td>'.$row["Time"].'</td>  
                     </tr>  
                ';  
           }  
           $output .= '</table>';  
           header("Content-Type: application/xls");   
           header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.xls");  
           echo $output;  
      }  
 }
```

so when I hit the export button on my index.php page it outputs the data in this format: [Google Sheets Link to the excel file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lYI37ejYmIE2GzUfeii85ZT4Br3Qu9JsKRLldgJcmB0/edit?usp=sharing)

```
<table class="table bordered="1">   
<tr>    
<th>Sort</th>   
<th>Unit Size</th>  
<th>Quantity</th>   
<th>Price per Unit</th> 
<th>Time</th>   
</tr>   

<tr>    
<td></td>   
<td>45</td> 
<td>0</td>  
<td>0</td>  
<td>2016-08-11 16:53:12</td>    
</tr>   

<tr>    
<td></td>   
<td>6</td>  
<td>0</td>  
<td>0</td>  
<td>2016-08-11 16:53:12</td>    
</tr>   
</table>
```

so it outputs the right data but just the formating is off, here is what it looks like on the index.php page:
[What the excel file should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyOHn.png)
do if anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong that be wonderful!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: MS Excel can open html file and show data from table as excel spreadsheet, however this is NOT a valid xls file, so google-spreadsheets cannot read it correctly.

Comment: you'd be better writing the data as csv formatted data rather than html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps a little bit of a cheat outputting as csv rather than `proper xls` but it should more or less work.

```
<?php

    if( isset( $_POST["export_excel"] ) ) {

        ob_clean();

        $sql = 'select * from logs order by item';
        $result = mysqli_query( $connect, $sql );  
        if( mysqli_num_rows( $result ) > 0){


            $delimiter=',';
            $enclosure='"';

            /* rather than create an actual file, use an output buffer and write to that */
            $output=fopen('php://output','w+');

            /* add column headers */
            $headers=array( 'Unit Size', 'Quantity', 'Price_per_Unit', 'Time' );

            /* write the headers to the output stream */
            fputcsv( $output,$headers, $delimiter, $enclosure );

            /* loop through recordset and add that to the stream */
            while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
                fputcsv( $output, $row, $delimiter, $enclosure );
            }

            fclose( $output );

            /* set the headers accordingly */
            header('Content-Type: application/csv');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.csv');

            /* send the new content */
            ob_flush();

        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you want to export data into excel. In that case just changing the headers won't work because excel is not about table tags, What you need is a library for writing the contents into an excel format file and then make user download the same. Have a look at [phpExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel).

You can also see in the example [here](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/01simple-download-pdf.php) on how to properly insert data in excel using the same.